# Call sales order model inside console command object

Tags: magento2, module, upgrade

After ugprade to **M2 2.2.4**, I got problem in my custom module. The module has console command but upon upgrade I'm getting **"Area code is not set"**. After few hours of debugging, I found out that the root cause is calling **\Magento\Sales\Model\Order** object as parameter in my **__Construct** function.

Replacing it with reourceModel will work, but I'm just wondering why the main order model is not working. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

**\Magento\Sales\Model\Order**

To:

**\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory**